# Why do we think that the relation $\vec{\mu}_L=\frac{e}{2m_e}\vec{L}$ will be valid in quantum mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, angular-momentum, operators, magnetic-moment

Assuming the electrons to revolve round the nucleus in circular orbits and using the fact from classical electromagnetism that a current loop behaves like a magnetic dipole of dipole moment $\vec{\mu}_L=\int I \vec{dA}$ where $\int \vec{dA}$ is the area of the loop and $I$ is the current through the loop one can relate the magnetic moment $\vec{\mu}_L$ with the classical orbital angular momentum $\vec{L}=\vec{r}\times\vec{p}$ as $$\hspace{5.5cm}\vec{\mu}_L=\frac{e}{2m_e}\vec{L}\hspace{5.5cm}(1)$$ where the symbols have their obvious meaning. What I find uncomfortable is that this derivation is entirely classical. This is because the electrons don't really move in trajectories but are described by wavefunctions and also, in quantum mechanics $\vec{\mu}_L$ and $\vec{L}$ are both operators. We promptly use Eq.1 as a valid operator relation in quantum mechanics: $$\hspace{5.5cm}\hat{\vec{\mu}}_L=\frac{e\hbar}{2m_e}\frac{\hat{\vec{L}}}{\hbar}\hspace{5.5cm}(2)$$

Q1. But why? Why do we expect the quantum mechanical operators $\hat{\vec{\mu}}_L$ and $\hat{\vec{L}}$ to be related? Is Eq.2 a postulate new or is there something simple I am missing?

Q2. Can we take any classical relation, promote the dynamical variables to operators and demand that the relation will hold quantum mechanically?

Q3. Is there a way of deriving/reproducing Eq.2 by rigorous means from the formalism of quantum mechanics?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correspondence_principle

Comment: This is no new postulate. You always do this. The postulate of QM is that you're supposed to replace the dynamical observables by self-adjoint operators. This is what you do, for example, when you translate $\textbf{L}=\textbf{r}\times\textbf{p}$ to $\hat{\textbf{L}}=\hat{\textbf{r}}\times\hat{\textbf{p}}$.  @mithusengupta123

Comment: can we take **any** classical relation between dynamical variables, promote them to operators and such a relation will be valid in quantum mechanics at the operator level?

Comment: Yes. Unless there is a commutativity problem. Since $L_i=i\hbar \epsilon_{ijk}x_jp_k$ and wo different components of $x_j$ and $p_k$ that appear in the definition of $L_i$ commute, there is no ordering ambiguity! Such an ordering ambiguity exists in defining the quantum mechanical counterpart of the Runge-Lenz vector or radial component of liner momentum $p_r$. In these cases, the quantum operator definitions is somewhat different from classical definitions.

Comment: Does https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/138400/37496 help assuage your concerns?

Answer (score 1):

Quantum operators have to be related in the same way that classical quantities are, in order for the [Correspondence Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correspondence_principle) to hold. Otherwise, expectation values of the operators would not obey classical physics in the limit of large quantum numbers.