# How is the magnetic dipole moment operator defined?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, magnetic-moment, dipole-moment

In quantum mechanics, the electric dipole moment operator is defined as $$\hat{\vec D}=q\hat{\vec r}$$ where $q$ is the electric charge of the distribution. This is directly obtained by promoting classical dynamical variable ${\vec r}$ to quantum operator $\hat{\vec r}$.  Can we a define magnetic dipole moment operator from the classical formula $$\vec\mu=\int I d\vec{A}$$ as a straightforward generalization?

Comment: Do you know that the mag. moment is related with the spin or more general the angular momentum? In my opinion it does not make sense to stick to the classical description and adding quantum mechanical objects (such as spin). May I ask why you are interested in sticking to the classical description?

Comment: Yes, I know that in general, ${\vec \mu}\propto {\vec L}+2{\vec S}$. Here, the question is different. Quantum operators are often defined from their classical counterparts. Consider kinetic energy. Classically, the kinetic energy $T=\frac{p^2}{2m}$ becomes in QM, $\hat{T}=\frac{\hat{p}^2}{2m}$. Similarly, potential energy $V(x)$ becomes $V(\hat{x})$ etc. I also want to know and understand whether the origin of magnetic dipole moment, whether orbital or spin, can be explained classically.

Comment: [Duplicate](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/462814/why-do-we-think-that-the-relation-vec-mu-l-frace2m-e-vecl-will-be-va) ?

Comment: I guess ok. But it will be much harder to calculate the current from the wavefucntion.